# Formula translation from Wolfram Python Client Library to Python usable string

Tags: python, wolfram-client

I try to use the Wolfram Python client library to evaluate
a differential equation in Python.

This does not work smoothly, but using

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
session = WolframLanguageSession()


with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
    result = s.evaluate_wrap("TexForm[DSolve[y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x][[1, 1, 2]]]")
```

As you see, I already tried to bring DSolve into TexForm in this expression to be able to read it in Python.

But with using TexForm or without I get something like

```
(With TexForm)
Global`TexForm[Times[Power[E, Times[-1, Global`x]], C[1]]]

(Without TexForm)
Times[Power[E, Times[-1, Global`x]], C[1]]
```

How can I bring that into a form, that I can use in Python, i.e.
in sympy or even a LaTex String?

Comment: How about `CForm` ? That gives `C(1)/Power(E,x)`.

Comment: That would be great, but the Python client gives ```CForm[Times[Power[E, Times[-1, Global`x]], C[1]]]``` for that. Although it evaluates well in Mathematica.

Comment: Wait I'm confused, you're calling Mathematica from Python, correct? Why do you need TeXForm at all ? Just remove it.

Comment: Yes, but if I remove it, I get the second result that I showed in the question and it is in a tree form. Even getting the result as it is given out in a Mathematica Notebook would be great.

Comment: For a moment there I thought it was an encoding issue and I did `result = s.evaluate("DSolve[y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x][[1, 1, 2]]".encode('ascii'))` but that just returned a string back, not an expression. I think there's a bug here, because I can't seem to do any `DSolve`'s. Other functions like `Solve[x^2==3,x]` work fine.

Comment: I also tried `(First[y[x] /. (DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x])])//InputForm` to eliminate the `[[1,1,2]]`, added an initial condition, and use `InputForm` in case the generated parameter was the problem. But it still fails.

Comment: How did you manage to get ```Times[Power[E, Times[-1, Global`x]], C[1]]``` ? All I get is `String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, pkspec1], Slot[1]]`

Comment: Yes, the result that you get is a known error of DSolve used in Python. It will throw the errors you see, but still return a result. Try to print the result and you will see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the `CForm / FortranForm / TeXForm` etc. is unevaluated. However, if you convert it into a string it will work:

```
with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
    result = s.evaluate_wrap("With[{eq = {D[y[x], x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}}, DSolve[eq, y[x], x]]")
    tmp = s.evaluate_wrap("ToString[CForm[{}]]".format(result.result[0][0][1]))
```

The result: `WolframKernelEvaluationResult<expression=Power(E,-x)>`

Replacing `CForm` with `TeXForm`, we get `WolframKernelEvaluationResult<expression=e^{-x}>`

I think the reason for this behaviour is hinted at in the documentation and a sentence like this appears in the 'possible issues' section for each kind of output form:

> *Even when an output omits CForm from the top level, it is not stripped from subexpressions*

*Mathematica* does not seem to redirect the special output forms to the normal output as strings, so that's why we need `ToString` here.